# Live Page Updates using the Play Framework or addon

Tags: java, frameworks, playframework, meteor

I am fairly new to the Play framework, although I have used Java a lot in academic environments.  I have a bit of a newbie question regarding the Play framework:  Curious to know if there is something equivalent to Meteor.js "Live Page Updates"  feature (https://www.meteor.com/).  It doesn't achieve this through polling (client requesting refresh from server at timed intervals), which is great since polling can get taxing on the server.

I am not too familiar with exactly how it's done behind what I code for a site, but I would love to know if there is something similar to it in Play.

Comment: What does meteor use then, websockets?

Comment: Meteor uses an invented pub/sub protocol for WebSockets/SockJS called DDP. You can read its [preliminary specification here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/livedata/DDP.md). I believe someone has written a Java client for DDP, but I'm unsure how you could replicate Meteor's functionality in another framework. Meteor is built from the bottom up with reactivity in mind. It would take a lot of code to get the same kind of system going in another framework.

Comment: @Cuberto, thank you.  That's what I needed to know.  I really like this functionality, but it's difficult trying a preview version of a framework like meteor for a in-house dev project, despite how much I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current mainstream way to do that on Play is to use websockets and an angular-like framework on the UI.

Take a look at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/JavaWebSockets for Play's Java websockets documentation for an example.